# Delete Duplicates on the column without deleting the entire row

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I want to delete the duplicate data on the same column, without deleting the entire row the data is contained in, so the data>delete dups will not work on this problem

the Data inside the cell, not the entire row, I want to leave the cells blank when the dups are deleted, why do I not want the entire row to get deleted? because the column next to this column also has data so deleting the entire row is not an

Comment: Please include the code you are using in your question, otherwise it is unlikely you will get any help, assuming you finish your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code for you,

```html
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim iCounter As Integer

'   Please set your range here
    Set rngData = Range("A1:A1000")
 
    For Each cCell In rngData
        If Not (IsEmpty(cCell.Value) Or Trim(cCell.Value) = "") Then
            For iCounter = cCell.Row + 1 To rngData.Rows.Count
                If cCell.Value = rngData(iCounter).Value Then rngData(iCounter).Value = ""
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It worked thank you very much! now to incorporate it in my macro